# How to send a pre-defined text of a <form> element into action page, without having the user to type

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, textfield

As you know, the `<input type="text" name = "input_field">` element creates a space for the user to type in an HTML form. But in this case, I know what the user is going to enter.

For instance, the user wants to send 'hello' to the action page. It isn't a particular piece of information like his/her name, email id, etc. It will be the same for everyone. Then why not just create a button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="click to send 'hello'">
```

When the user will click on the button, 'hello' will be sent to the action page specified in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` element.

How do I do it? Also, I need to mention that I am not much experienced in HTML or JS, so I would appreciate a beginner-like solution.

I apologize if this question already exists somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`<input type="hidden" name="input_field" value="hello">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) :-) Happy coding!

Comment: You can use [a hidden field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).

Comment: T.J Crowder, would you please give an example?

Comment: That *is* the example. :-) I went looking for a duplicate but couldn't find one, so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include predefined information when submitting a form by using a [`type="hidden"` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden):

```html
<input type="hidden" name="input_field" value="hello">
```

That doesn't appear visibly on the page, but is submitted just like any other field when you submit the form.

Comment: *(I couldn't find a dupetarget, which surprises me enough that I know it's there...somewhere...)*

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to create a form where few fields will have predefined information

I would suggest **not to hide** the input according to the `UI/UX perspective` but instead, you can show those fields as `read-only`.

In this way, the user will have an idea of predefined values

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="number" disabled readonly id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```